# Linking Fortran 77 source code and subprogram

Tags: function, fortran, gfortran, fortran77, linker-errors

I am trying to compile the following test program, named `test_matrix.f`:

```
PROGRAM test_matrix
  IMPLICIT NONE
  REAL*8 A(2,2), B(2,2), Bt(2,2), C(2,2)
  REAL detA, detB, detC
  REAL getdet
  A(1,1) = 1
  A(1,2) = 2
  A(2,1) = 3
  A(2,2) = 4
  B(1,1) = 1
  B(1,2) = 2
  B(2,1) = 0
  B(2,2) = 1
  detA = getdet(A,2)
  detB = getdet(B,2)
  WRITE (*,*) detA
  WRITE (*,*) detB
  END PROGRAM
```

where `getdet` is a standard external subprogram for the calculation of the determinant of a square matrix, as described in https://www.scribd.com/doc/46792210/FORTRAN77-Function-to-calculate-matrix-determinant, stored in the file `getdet.f` in the same folder.

When I try to compile the program with the command

```
gfortran getdet.f test_matrix.f -o test_matrix.out
```

The output for the two determinants is

```
0.00000000
0.00000000
```

which is clearly wrong. But if I add lines to the program file `getdet.f` so that it prints the result each time the program `getdet` is invoked from the main program `test_matrix.f`, then what I get becomes

```
determinant is:  -2.0000000000000000
determinant is:   1.0000000000000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
```

which clearly suggests that whatever the subprogram calculates is not fed back into the main program `test_matrix.f`.

Did I link the programs in an erroneous way? (Some google search suggests that this is the way to link multiple source code files.) How should I remedy the problem? Thanks all in advance.

Comment: As the output in the function is `-2.0000000000000000` it looks like you should be declaring the function as double precision, not real.  Can you test that?

Comment: Ah I think you're absolutely right.... should declare `REAL*8` in the main program. Now it gives me the right answers. Problem solved.

Comment: It is a good time to consider looking at using an the interface block so that the compiler checks for double and tells you when you compile.

Comment: It would also be good to move away from real*8 into a standard conforming way of declaring variables